# How do I pass a share from a hyper-v windows 2012r2 image of Ubuntu Server to the network?

Tags: samba, hyper-v, windows-server-2012, ubuntu-14.04

I've been using Ubuntu Server 14.04LTS for a while now and it does what I want. Recently I started experimenting with email and while I got it setup right, it occurred to me that I could do the same thing easier in Windows Server 2012r2 with hmailserver. Since I'm lazy I went a head and installed Windows Server 2012r2 onto a SSD in my server that was running Ubuntu Server 14.04LTS.

It did everything I wanted except there wasn't a good BTRFS replacement. I like the ease of management, snapshots, and the raidz2 functions. Yes, storage spaces can do raidz2, but it can't resize an array once made and the speed is crap. So I took the next lazy step.

I turned Hyper-V on. I then made a virtual machine, off-lined the harddisks with Ubuntu and the BTRFS and joined them to the machine. It boots fine and works great with dynamic ram enabled. I bridged the network and all machines work fine with it.

Question: If I put the Ubuntu Virtual Machine on an internal network setting; how do I give it an ip address, and how do I get the samba share to the Windows Server 2012r2 machine, and finally; how do I put that share out onto the physical network?

I'm asking because I'm curious and I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Why not place them both on your physical network? Otherwise another option is to give one of them a second NIC.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. I've been looking at the setup and I'm starting to think it would have been better to use VirtualBox with extensions and put Windows Server onto that instead. I'll do some tests to see which is better.